# Any Way to Mirror the Data Needed Only to Load the index.html Page of a Site?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to mirror a site's landing page to do testing on it.

Is there any way to mirror only the first level of a site? I.E. all requests should become local files only for the first index page (not `wget -m -k`).

I'm comfortable with the command line so something using a CLI tool is perfectly acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To get only the index page of a site and its requisites, and convert them for local rendering, the following wget invocation (replacing the example URL with the one you want to mirror, of course) should produce the desired result, downloading the files into whatever directory you're in when you run it:

```
wget -r -l1 -k -nH http://www.example.com
```

The options signify as follows:

- -r:  Use recursive retrieval (follow links to other files).
- -l1: Limit recursion depth to 1 (follow links from the URL given on the command line, but not from the files thus retrieved).
- -k:  Rewrite absolute links in the retrieved files to refer to the downloaded versions, rather than the versions hosted on the mirrored webpage.
- -nH: Don't create per-hostname directories for the downloaded files (otherwise, if you're in e.g. `/home/example/mirror`, everything goes into `/home/example/mirror/www.example.com`).

Depending on how the target site is set up, you may need to do some additional munging on the retrieved files (for example, files with extension `.php` probably won't render correctly when opened from your disk, since there's no server giving a `Content-Type` header to tell your browser they contain HTML). This should serve as a pretty solid start, though.